# Issue accessing MS Access from IronPython

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to run scripts in MS Access using IronPython in Spotfire. Thus far, I can't even get connected to MS Access.

Here is my code for connecting:

```
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference("System.Data")

from System.Data import DataSet
from System.Data.Odbc import OdbcConnection, OdbcDataAdapter

connectString = (
    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    "Dbq=\\\olgwfap1\Data\Development Division\Res Surv Eng\Personal Folders\Pruet\Data Team\SPOTFIRE\TIDELANDS\Tidelands_Spotifre.accdb;"
    "Uid=Admin;PWd=;"
)

query = "Select * From FOP_Calc"


connection = OdbcConnection(connectString)
adaptor = OdbcDataAdapter(query, connection)
dataSet = DataSet()
connection.Open()
adaptor.Fill(dataSet)
connection.Close()
```

Executing this, I get the following error:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection,
>   OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()    at *stub*$296##296(Closure ,
>   CallSite , CodeContext , Object )    at
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.MatchCaller.Call2[T0,T1,TRet](Func`4
>   target, CallSite site, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.CallSite`1.UpdateAndExecute(Object[] args)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.UpdateDelegates.Update2[T,T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at $287##287(Closure , Scope ,
>   LanguageContext )    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport.IronPythonScriptEngine.ExecuteForDebugging(String
>   scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptService.ExecuteForDebugging(String
>   scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptManager.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__f()
>   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.Transaction(Executor
>   executor, Boolean visible, Boolean sticky, Guid stickyGuid)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.Transaction(String
>   displayName, Executor executor)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.Transaction(String
>   displayName, Executor executor)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptManager.ExecuteScriptForDebugging(String
>   scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scriptArguments, String& output)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Framework.Scripting.ScriptEditDialog.RunButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

The file name is definitely correct so I'm assuming it's the default driver giving it trouble.

If it makes any difference, my SpotFire (which hosts the IronPython) is a 64 bit installation and I'm using MSOffice 32 bit (I do have 64 and 32 bit MS Access ODBC drivers installed though).

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: `Provider=` is used for OleDb connections.  For ODBC, you need something like `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};` instead.  See [Microsoft Access accdb ODBC Driver connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/)

Comment: Good call, I made that change but am still getting the same error: connectString = (
 "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};"
 "Dbq=\\\olgwfap1\Data\Development Division\Res Surv Eng\Personal Folders\Pruet\Data Team\SPOTFIRE\TIDELANDS\Tidelands_Spotifre.accdb;"
)

Comment: Nuts!  Unfortunately my Python is way rusty and I've not done IronPython at all, so I don't know what's wrong now.  One point I wonder about though ... are you positive you have both the 32 and 64 bit Access drivers installed?  I understood that is not a configuration MS supports.

Comment: You are correct, I thought I did but trying to actually configure the 64 bit version throws an error saying "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application". So maybe it is a driver issue?

Comment: And yes, I did trying with both *.mdb, *.accdb and just *.accdb

Comment: I've never attempted to install both the 32 and 64 bit Access drivers on the same machine.  I can't help you there.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IronPython script is running in a 64-bit environment then you would need to have the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed. Or conversely, if you have the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed (because you have 32-bit Office) then your IronPython script needs to be running in a 32-bit environment.

It is *possible* to force both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Access Database Engine to reside on the same machine but it is not recommended. It can cause problems with Office and is not a supported configuration.